# Javascript Exception : unhandled method size()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use JQuery's tablesorter to sort my tables, but I'm having an issue with empty tables throwing exceptions. So I added a condition to my script, but now the problem comes from the condition. :

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    if($("#printerTable").find("tbody").size()>0){
        $("#printerTable").tablesorter({ sortList: [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]] 
});
```

The exception is :

> Javascript execution error : The Object doesn't handle property or method size()

(Translated from French)

So I tried using `.length` method instead, to no avail

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    if($("#printerTable").find("tbody").length > 0){
        $("#printerTable").tablesorter({ sortList: [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]] });
    }
});
```

The exception becomes :

> JavaScript Execution error :  impossible to obtain property "0" from a null reference

Can you see what I'm not seeing here? Thanks!

Comment: `.length` is a property not a method, so use it like `$("#printerTable").find("tbody").length > 0`

Comment: @Satpal This gives me another exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#printerTable tbody').children().length;
```

Try this, using `children()` method instead.
I hope it will work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `size()` was deprecated in version 1.8 and removed completely in jQuery 3.0, simply because the native `length` ***property*** does the same thing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $("#printerTable").find("tbody").length > 0 ) {
        $("#printerTable").tablesorter({ 
            sortList: [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]]
        });
    }
});
```

The second error isn't really related to the posted code, unless you're actually missing the closing to the tablesorter function and the `if` condition.

Most likely it's the tablesorter plugin not receiving the correct arguments

Comment: Ah yeah, but it's strange because it works fine with non-empty tables, or at least I have no exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

maybe when you are using some properties,you can try it in chrome!
like, this:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.dir($("#printerTable"));
    //you will see all the properties! 

});
```

and, you will know using the right property!